# How do you display track position in Yahoo Media Player Playlist

Tags: php

I am using the YahooMediaPlayer on my website, but would like to know if its possible to get the track position (within the playlist loaded). At the moment I add mp3 files to the page via href tags which YMP picks up. Ive tried using FireBug to find the track-ID but cant seem to see it anywhere.

Please can you help?